# Unable to makemigrations while using postgres

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am new to pgsql, can not configure this error while I'm trying to makemigration in the Django-rest app.
what should I install? I've installed the requirements.txt which consists of :

PyJWT==1.7.1 pytz==2021.1 sqlparse==0.4.1 psycopg2>=2.8 psycopg2-binary>=2.8 python_dotenv==0.16

the error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: You DB server is offline or misconfigured.

Comment: I'm really a newbie :( how can check this out? should I install postgresql-13.2-1-windows-x64.exe?  I'm using win10.

Comment: Is it matter to use Postgre? If you wanna just do practice and you just starter, you should start from simpler db as Sqlite. It comes with box and it is not required any extra acts.

Answer (score 1):

The Db server is offline so you'll need to enable this. for windows do the following:

Start -> Control panel -> Administration -> Services -> postgresql-x64-12 - start or restartc

You should be fine to make the migrations once the server is running. It is possible you may need to check the config in your settings but after that you should be good to go :)